# How can i control the variable order on Com interoperability?

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have this struct in C++ code ( C++ Com server )

```
struct
{
    int     f1;
    double  f2[3];
    int     f3;
};
```

I wrote some code on C# that call this C++ COM method and i get this struct back from this method.

I found out that the struct that i get back have different order variable. 
The return value struct is (Fields reordered)

```
struct
{
    double   f2[3];
    int      f1;    
    int      f3;
};
```

Someone can explain how can i keep the original order ? 
Why i got it back in different order ?

( the struct come from other application that i can't control - so using 'StructLayout' is not helping )

Comment: Hmm, how do you know?  The layout of a managed struct is not discoverable.  Only looking at a memory dump could give you a hint.  A struct like this always gets marshaled, it is not blittable due to the array.  So it doesn't matter, getting automatic layout is preferable since that produces a smaller size.  There is a 4 bytes of padding before the array member and 4 bytes of padding at the end of the unmanaged struct.  No padding at all in the managed struct, saves 8 bytes.

Comment: i checked the memory map the size Field alignment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`StructLayoutAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in your C# code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
```

Comment: the struct come from other application that i can't control on so this is not hepling

Comment: @Yanshof perhaps your can clarify your question better.